# How to compare elements of two columns in two different dataframes in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark, databricks

[var_distinct_allevt.display()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioK9C.png)

I'm trying two compare two DataFrames (each one has 1 column called event_0). The columns contain elements, some are equal, some are different.
My goal is to do a comparison between these 2 columns in order to discover which elements are the same, if any is missing in one of the columns etc.

My idea was to do an outer join to have a result with two columns that would have all the elements (the ones that are present in the two dataframes would appear and the ones that are not present in one of the df would appear as 'null' in the column of the respective df), in that way I could easily see where is the difference.

The code I used is `all_components = orig_distinct_allevt.join(var_distinct_allevt, ['event_0'] , 'full')` but the result im getting is one column with all the elements. The image is one of the dataframes, the other one is the original and has one less element

Comment: Could you provide a sample of each of your dataframes?

Comment: ok I've add one of them (I'm not being able to add both of them) @Zorgoth